# JSTL- set background color with condition

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

I am new to Java, JSTL, CSS, JSP... any of Java related and web application world.
and I am learning and making my own web program at the same time (using Spring MVC).

Now I am going to set 2 different background color by condition using JSTL in .jsp file. 
My codition is median. so logic in jsp file with jstl should be like this:

```
if (value < median)  
// set background: green
else
// set background: red
```

I have done all the calculations for median value in Controller. 
So my controller delivers median 
and both the integer type and the string type of data

(I noticed that integer type of data can't be presented on a browser page, correct? [Q1]

So Integer type for conditional operation with median, string type for presentation on a browser)

```
model.addAttribute("dataNo", dataNo);
model.addAttribute("dataStr", dataStr);
model.addAttribute("dataInt", dataInt);
model.addAttribute("median", median);
```

My. jsp like this

(my table is increasing colum)

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="dataNoValue" items="${dataNo}">
                <th>${dataNoValue}</th>
            </c:forEach>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="dataStrValue" items="${dataStr}">
                <th class="${dataInt < median ? 'background-color: green':'background-color: red'}">${dataStrValue}</th> -- [Q2] 
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Yes, [Q2] is wrong, any suggestions? appreciated!

Comment: It should be style instead of class. <th style="${dataInt < median ? 'background-color: green':'background-color: red'}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either replace class attribute by style attribute like this:

```
<th style="${dataInt < median ? 'background-color: green':'background-color: red'}">${dataStrValue}</th>
```

or create two classes green and red and use them like this :

```
<style>
 .green{background-color: green}
 .red{background-color: red}
</style>

<th class="${dataInt < median ? 'green':'red'}">${dataStrValue}</th>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another issue...at first, explanation about the data type,  median is double type, and dataInt is List<Integer>... Can it be problem when the data type is mismatch, can't use conditional logic? it seems like this is causing problem.. Did I have to convert , dataInt , median as the same time to compare? and how?